# Django-Filter: {{ field.value }} is Empty when rendering form fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter, django-taggit

I'm using the [Django-Filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io) library **!important**. For tags, I'm using [Django-taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I built the following **filter.py**:

```
class TaskFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    tags = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Task.tags.most_common())

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['tags']
```

However, when I pass this `filter` to the template, it doesn't render the tags properly. In particular {{ field.value }} is empty. Let's look at the following cases:

---

## CASE 1.

```
# template.html
{{ filter.form.tags.errors }}
{% for field in filter.form.tags %}
<label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}"></label>
{{ field.value }}
{% endfor %}

# out
<label for="id_tags_0"></label>
<label for="id_tags_1"></label>
<label for="id_tags_2"></label>
```

## CASE 2.

```
# template.html
{{ filter.form.tags.errors }}
{% for field in filter.form.tags %}
<label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}"></label>
{{ field }}
{% endfor %}

# out
<label for="id_tags_0"></label>
<label for="id_tags_0"><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="4" id="id_tags_0">Tag 1</label>
<label for="id_tags_1"></label>
<label for="id_tags_1"><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="1" id="id_tags_1">Tag 2</label>
<label for="id_tags_2"></label>
<label for="id_tags_2"><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="2" id="id_tags_2">Tag 3</label>
```

## CASE 3.

```
# template.html
{{ filter.form.tags.errors }}
{% for field in filter.form.tags %}
{{ field }}
{{ field.label_tag }}
{% endfor %}

#out
<label for="id_tags_0"><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="4" id="id_tags_0">Tag 1</label>
<label for="id_tags_1"><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="1" id="id_tags_1">Tag 2</label>
<label for="id_tags_2"><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="2" id="id_tags_2">Tag 3</label>
```

I'm trying to understand why this happens. Why can't I get the values [as stated in the docs](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjVycaW5pHaAhUjJcAKHR_vDD0QygQIKzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.djangoproject.com%2Fen%2F2.0%2Ftopics%2Fforms%2F%23rendering-fields-manually&usg=AOvVaw1_FC6ri_D1aROkABN8fZn_)

## STEPS TO REPRODUCE

```
pip install django-filter + add 'django_filters' to APPS
pip install django-taggit + add 'taggit' to APPS

# models.py
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    tags = TaggableManager()

# Use the API to create an object.
t = Task.objects.create(title="Title")
t.tags.add("Tag 1","Tag 2")

# views.py
def view(request):
    f = TaskFilter(request.GET, queryset=Task.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'filter': f}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you iterate over `filter.form.tags` you're not iterating over a set of form fields, but instead over a set of individual choices for the `tags` field. This is why `field.value` doesn't work.

This should work instead:

```
{{ filter.form.tags.errors }}
{% for choice in filter.form.tags %}
    <label for="{{ choice.id_for_label }}"></label>
    {{ choice.tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

Where `tag` is an attribute that exists on each choice, which will render the checkbox input for that choice.

This is documented in the documentation for [RadioSelect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect):

> To get more granular, you can use each radio button’s `tag`, `choice_label` and `id_for_label` attributes.

Further down, the documentation for [CheckBoxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple) says that the same logic applies for it too.

Comment: Thanks this explains my question. One more thing, is it possible (using shortcuts, in simple way) to check whether at least one tag from this group is checked?

Comment: P.S. I can't award the +50 rep for 6 more hours

Comment: I'm not aware of any shortcut for that - think you would have to iterate over all the choices to find out which ones are selected.

Comment: Thanks, I made a solution using `request.GET['tags']` in Django views and passed it to template if anyone has this problem.